# Crash while using Datecomponents having larger differences

Tags: ios, swift, nsdatecomponents

Crashing for large interval between dates while trying to use date components in swift (for example dates used is 16 August 1979 to 11 may 2053)
The code for date components is

```
ComponentsforDetail = (Calendar.current as NSCalendar).components([.second], from: FromDateValue!, to: ToValueDate!, options: [])
```

Using breakpoints i found out the thread_exc happens in an assembly line code

```
libswiftFoundation.dylib`static Foundation.DateComponents._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC (Swift.Optional<__ObjC.NSDateComponents>) -> Foundation.DateComponents:
    0x16cf280 <+0>:  push   {r4, r5, r7, lr}
    0x16cf284 <+4>:  add    r7, sp, #8
    0x16cf288 <+8>:  sub    sp, sp, #4
    0x16cf28c <+12>: mov    r4, r0
    0x16cf290 <+16>: mov    r0, #0
    0x16cf294 <+20>: str    r0, [sp]
    0x16cf298 <+24>: cmp    r4, #0
    0x16cf29c <+28>: beq    0x16cf2dc                 ; <+92>
    0x16cf2a0 <+32>: mov    r0, r4
    0x16cf2a4 <+36>: bl     0x17a42e8                 ; symbol stub for: objc_retain
    0x16cf2a8 <+40>: mov    r1, sp
    0x16cf2ac <+44>: mov    r0, r4
    0x16cf2b0 <+48>: bl     0x174ed80                 ; function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed, Arg[2] = Dead> of static Foundation.DateComponents._conditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC (__ObjC.NSDateComponents, result : inout Swift.Optional<Foundation.DateComponents>) -> Swift.Bool
    0x16cf2b4 <+52>: mov    r0, r4
    0x16cf2b8 <+56>: bl     0x17a42d8                 ; symbol stub for: objc_release
    0x16cf2bc <+60>: ldr    r5, [sp]
    0x16cf2c0 <+64>: cmp    r5, #0
    0x16cf2c4 <+68>: beq    0x16cf2e0                 ; <+96>
    0x16cf2c8 <+72>: mov    r0, r4
    0x16cf2cc <+76>: bl     0x17a42d8                 ; symbol stub for: objc_release
    0x16cf2d0 <+80>: mov    r0, r5
    0x16cf2d4 <+84>: sub    sp, r7, #8
    0x16cf2d8 <+88>: pop    {r4, r5, r7, pc}
->  0x16cf2dc <+92>: trap   (Here is the breakpoint exception Happening)
    0x16cf2e0 <+96>: trap
```

I think this is an issue with integer format because anything greater than 68 years is causing this crash in Datecomponents for seconds
I've used Playground to identify the issue the code used in playground is

```
import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"
let dateString1 = "1979-11-28 07:57:20 +0000"
let dateString2 = "2048-11-29 10:59:00 +0000"

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
let date1 = formatter.date(from: dateString1)!
let date2 = formatter.date(from: dateString2)!

let calendar = NSCalendar.current
let components1 = (Calendar.current as NSCalendar).components([NSCalendar.Unit.minute], from: date1, to: date2, options: NSCalendar.Options.init(rawValue: 0))
let components2 = (Calendar.current as NSCalendar).components([.second], from: date1, to: date2, options: [])
```

Anything for date2 greater than year 2047 will result this error

Comment: share more code related to this crash.

Comment: @KKRocks I've tried using playground to find the exact cause I've added the code used in playground in question

Comment: @Krunal please check the code used in playground it depicts the same error?

Comment: BTW - why are you using `NSCalendar` instead of `Calendar`? Of course the same issue appears either way.

Comment: @rmaddy I am using Calendar in the app The NSCalendar was used in checking the code in playground So should  i try to write a guard in the seconds Datecomponent to avoid crash?

Comment: What guard could you write? I'd submit a bug report to Apple.

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah writing guard might be not feasible here  I'll have to think about another solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to happen when the `dateComponents` of `Calendar` is used to get the number of seconds between two dates and the resulting number of seconds is too large to fit in a signed 32-bit integer (2^31).

An alternate solution is to use `Date timeIntervalSince` to get the number of seconds between two dates.

Your updated code becomes:

```
let dateString1 = "1979-11-28 07:57:20 +0000"
let dateString2 = "2048-11-29 10:59:00 +0000"

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
let date1 = formatter.date(from: dateString1)!
let date2 = formatter.date(from: dateString2)!

let seconds = date2.timeIntervalSince(date1)
let components1 = Calendar.current.dateComponents([ .minute ], from: date1, to: date2)
let minutes = components1.minute
```

This gives `2177636500` for seconds and `36293941` for minutes.

Comment: They must be using 32 bit Int internally because that is close to the max for a 32bit signed Integer.  On a 64 bit platform  Int max is 9223372036854775807 which is 292,471,208,677.536 years, or many times the entire span of the existance of the universe so you should never have a problem representing time in seconds as a 64 bit Int.